# Counter example regarding series and improper integral

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from Wade, Intro to Real Analysis.

I am looking for a counter example to:

Suppose $a_k = f(k)$ for some continuous function $f: [1, \infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$

such that $ f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges then $\int_1^\infty f(x) dx$ converges.

The best response I have come up with so far is:
$ f(k) = \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$  if $x > 1$, and $0 $ if $x =0 $

But then I don't think it's continuous. In order to have improper integral diverge, it seems to me the function has to be unbounded at at least one point. But then the continuity restriction forbids such it seems.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think so? Because the problem as given by the prof says give a counter example. And as a hint he says the f does not satisfy the requirements of the integral test...

Comment: For $k$ a positive integer, let $f(k)=0$ and $f(k+1/2)=1/k$. Then connect the dots with straight line segments.

Comment: @graydad: This is only true if you assume that $f$ is nonincreasing, or at least place further assumptions on $f$. Otherwise, you can easily get $f(k) =0$ for all $k$, but so that $\int f$ still diverges, see the example of David Mitra.

Comment: Thank you! That was an epiphany.